# GPG error in Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, apt, gpg, aptitude

I got error after `aptitude update` command:

```
Err http://archive.debian.org lenny/non-fre Packages                                                                            
  404 Not Found [IP: 209.87.16.41 80]
Fetched 194kB in 6s (31.3kB/s)                                                                                                  
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1520281423 KEYEXPIRED 1337087218
W: GPG error: http://archive.debian.org lenny/updates Release: The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1356982504
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/dists/lenny/non-fre/binary-i386/Packages  404 Not Found [IP: 209.87.16.41 80]

E: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

What does it mean and how to fix that?

Content of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main contrib non-fre
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-security/ lenny/updates main contrib non-
free
```

Comment: As we are dealing with a very old repo, I do not know if key renewal will work at all. The easiest way out is putting an old date, around 2011-2012

Answer (score 1):

This line has a typo at the end:

```
deb http://archive.debian.org/debian-archive/debian/ lenny main contrib non-fre
```

Add the missing e to `non-free` to fix the `404 Not found` and the `Failed to fetch...` error.

The `GPG error` messages indicate that Lenny's package distribution keys have expired. Since this is an archived distribution, this is as expected. But it looks like it's already being treated as just a warning. But [this bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=862515) has some options you can use.

Comment: There is a previous thread from this same user where another user brought up the possibility of using `Acquire::Check-Valid-Until` and then checked Debian repos, and arrived to the conclusion this option was not yet implemented by Lenny time. I would nevertheless advise as usual in this group to point out those commands in the answer instead of leaving only a link. However, unless I am reading wrongly, the user in the bug report says the commands did not work, which confirms this was not indeed implemented yet on Lenny.